# To overlay a custom dialog for parent Activity to all views including child activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, android-context

I need to show a custom dialog overlays over all child activities. But that dialog's base context is background. Is it possible?. This is used for custom lock to whole application after wake up(Screen On). I have a broad cast receiver to manage that. But that receiver is registered through parent activity. When the screen go to sleep from parent activity that dialog/process executes correctly. But the screen go to sleep from child activity that dialog shows background of child activity, when I will back to the parent activity then that shows.
I think this occurred on dialog's context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an `Activity` instead of a `Dialog`. Set your `Activity` theme to emulate a `Dialog` in the manifest.

**Example** - AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Then, you will have more flexibility and control over its display.